# Range activation in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, range, worksheet

I was wondering if there is an alternative for the following code:

```
Dim Arr() as Variant
Arr = Range("A1:I511")
```

that refers to a specified worksheet. I tried the following

```
Dim Arr() as Variant
Arr = Range(Sheets("list").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("list").Cells(511, 9))
```

Is there another way to write this? I want to have something like this:

```
Dim Arr() as Variant
Arr = worksheets("list").range(Cells(1, 1),Cells(511, 9))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of other ways to write this, perhaps most simply:

```
arr = Sheets("list").Range("A1:I511").Value
```

But here is the problem with your attempts:

`Cells(_row_, _column_)` returns a range object, which evaluates to its default property (the `.Value` property.  So when you do:

`Range(Sheets("list").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("list").Cells(511,9))`

You're actually doing this, which will raise an error *unless* the unlikely circumstance that these cells contain a string value that can be interpreted as a range address like "$A$1" or "$J$5:$Q$459", etc.

`Range(Sheets("list").Cells(1, 1).Value, _
    Sheets("list").Cells(511,9).Value)`

Try this instead:

`Range(Sheets("list").Cells(1, 1).Address, _
    Sheets("list").Cells(511,9).Address).Value`

Or:

```
With Sheets("list")
   arr = Range(.Cells(1, 1).Address .Cells(511,9).Address).Value
End With
```

**NB** You can't *activate* a range on another sheet without first *activating* that sheet.  I would advise you against doing both. There is 99% of the time no reason to "activate" anything in VBA. See this for further explanation:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)